# Jquery error slow down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with my Jquery register validation.
I've a problem getting the error message back if you don't fill in a name.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#register').submit(function () {

        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var error = '<div class=\"states\"><li class=\"warning\"><strong>Fout!</strong><br /> U hebt geen naam opgegeven.</li> <br /></ul>';

        $(".states li").slideUp(750, function () {
            $('.states li').hide();

            $('#submit')
                .after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');


            $.post(action, {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                realname: $('#realnam').val(),
                pass: $('#pass').val(),
                repeatpass: $('#repeatpass').val(),
                mail: $('#mail').val(),
                mailadres: $('#mailadres').val(),
            });

            if (name == "") {
                $(error).slideDown('slow');
            }

        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

And my HTML code:

```
<script src="js/aanmelden.js"></script>
<?php 
include_once 'include/config.php';
?>

<div class="text-section">
<h1>Aanmelden</h1>
<p>Hier kunt u zich <strong>gratis</strong> aanmelden op <?php echo $sNaam; ?></p>
</div>
<div class="states">
<li class="warning"><strong>Waarschuwing</strong> Deze pagina is (nog) niet af, hier wordt aangewerkt.</li> <br />
</ul>

<form method="POST" action="bin/register.php" id="register">
<fieldset>                 
<legend>Naam</legend>
<label id="username">Gebruikersnaam:</label> 
<input type="text" class="text" name="gebruikersnaam" id="name" placeholder="Uw gebruikersnaam" /> <br />
<label id="realname">Uw echte naam:</label> &nbsp; 
<input type="text" class="text" name="echtenaam" id="realnam" placeholder="Uw echte naam" /> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Wachtwoord</legend>
<label id="password">Uw wachtwoord:</label> &nbsp;    
<input type="password" class="text" id="pass" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Uw wachtwoord"  /> <br />
<label id="repeatpassword">Uw wachtwoord nogmaals:</label>
<input type="password" class="text" id="repeatpass" name="hwachtwoord" placeholder="Uw wachtwoord nogmaals" /> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Mail</legend>
<label id="mailadres">Uw mail adres:</label> &nbsp; 
<input type="text" class="text" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Uw mail adres" /> <br />
<label id="repeatmail">Uw mail adres nogmaals:</label> 
<input type="text" class="text" name="hmail" id="mailadres" placeholder="Uw mail adres nogmaals" /> <br />``
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registreren" class="orange" id="submit" />           
<br />
</form>
```

My problem(demo at http://mijnrpg.eu and then the second tab). If you click on the button where it says "Registreren", you will see what I mean. It isn't giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        realname: $('#realnam').val(),
        pass: $('#pass').val(),
        repeatpass: $('#repeatpass').val(),
        mail: $('#mail').val(),
        mailadres: $('#mailadres').val(),
    });
```

use serialize

```
$('#register').serialize();
```

your post function would be

```
$.post(action,
  $('#register').serialize(),
  function(resp)
  {
   ///
  }
);
```

And to answer your question try

```
$('#name').val()==''
```

Here i slightly modified your code http://jsfiddle.net/eVA8s/10/
So basically what you want to do is create div tag with id error-message and set it style to hidden, 
second watch at your tags you have too many useless tags,
third always use firebug in firefox, or press f12 in chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your respons, it didn't work, I used it but their wasn't any change. I'm thinking the problem is with the error giving in Jquery, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I think it not work, bcs of error in javascript, try to put alert(1); after your post function and see if it work

Comment: I already did and then it worked, thats why I said that I thought the error wount show up because the fact about how I did the error display.

Comment: Thank for your respons, it still doesnt work. I've changed it with your tips: http://jsfiddle.net/eVA8s/

Answer (score 0):

you need to validate first not last. updated

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
$('.error').hide('fast');
$('.warning').hide('fast');
$('.succes').hide('fast');

    $('#register').submit(function () {

            if ($('#name').val() == "") 
{ 
$('.error').slideDown('slow'); return false; 
} 
    else
     {

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $(".states li").slideUp(750, function () {
            $('.states li').hide();

            $('#submit')
                .after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');


     $.post(action, {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                realname: $('#realnam').val(),
                pass: $('#pass').val(),
                repeatpass: $('#repeatpass').val(),
                mail: $('#mail').val(),
                mailadres: $('#mailadres').val(),
            });

        });

        return false;
    }


    });

});
</script>




<div class="text-section">
<h1>Aanmelden</h1>
<p>Hier kunt u zich <strong>gratis</strong> aanmelden op <?php echo $sNaam; ?></p>
</div>
<div class="states">
  <ul class="states">
    <li class="error"><strong>Fout</strong> Dit zullen ze zien wanneer ze iets fout hebben gedaan.</li>
    <br />
    <li class="warning"><strong>Waarschuwing</strong> Dit zullen ze zien wanneer er een onbekende fout is opgetreden.</li>
    <br />
    <li class="succes"><strong>Goed</strong> Dit zullen ze zien wanneer iets succesvol gegaan is.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form method="POST" action="bin/register.php" id="register">
<fieldset>                 
<legend>Naam</legend>
<label id="username">Gebruikersnaam:</label> 
<input type="text" class="text" name="gebruikersnaam" id="name" placeholder="Uw gebruikersnaam" /> <br />
<label id="realname">Uw echte naam:</label> &nbsp; 
<input type="text" class="text" name="echtenaam" id="realnam" placeholder="Uw echte naam" /> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Wachtwoord</legend>
<label id="password">Uw wachtwoord:</label> &nbsp;    
<input type="password" class="text" id="pass" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Uw wachtwoord"  /> <br />
<label id="repeatpassword">Uw wachtwoord nogmaals:</label>
<input type="password" class="text" id="repeatpass" name="hwachtwoord" placeholder="Uw wachtwoord nogmaals" /> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Mail</legend>
<label id="mailadres">Uw mail adres:</label> &nbsp; 
<input type="text" class="text" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Uw mail adres" /> <br />
<label id="repeatmail">Uw mail adres nogmaals:</label> 
<input type="text" class="text" name="hmail" id="mailadres" placeholder="Uw mail adres nogmaals" /> <br />``
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registreren" class="orange" id="submit" />           
<br />
</form>
```

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/amigura/2R2sh/7/)

Comment: Thank you, but still nothing.

Comment: where it says 'Waarschuwing' you are missing  error message in code

Comment: Yeah I know, but thats the thing I'm stuck on. I don't know how to display/show the error code in Jquery.

Comment: on your website it has the three error code in the code above there is none `<ul class="states"><li class="error"><strong>Fout</strong> Dit zullen ze zien wanneer ze iets fout hebben gedaan.</li> <br />
        <li class="warning"><strong>Waarschuwing</strong> Dit zullen ze zien wanneer er een onbekende fout is opgetreden.</li> <br /><li class="succes"><strong>Goed</strong> Dit zullen ze zien wanneer iets succesvol gegaan is.</li></ul>`

Comment: If you look now you see their is, I forgot to change UL into div class.